# Serverless: Serverless error while deployment

Tags: aws-serverless

Since I am a newbee to severless stack, I was trying to create a yml file that is used for deployment(NodeJS lambda function). But I can find a syntactical error while deployment.

Please find below the serverless.yml

```
service: secretManager

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  timeout: 300
  memorySize: 512
  region: us-east-2
  stage: ${opt:stage,'v1'}
  role: secretManager
  stackTags:
    ApplicationId: ACL_9999999
    Product: secretManager
    Project: secretManager

functions:
  getParams:
    handler: getFromParamStore.getParams
    role: secretManager

resources:
  Resources:
    secretManager:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        Policies:
        - PolicyName: myPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2017'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow 
                Action:
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                  - ssm:GetParameters
                  - ssm:GetParameter
                  - ssm:DescribeParameters
                Resource:
                  - 'Fn::Join':
                    - ':'
                    - 'arn:aws:logs'
                    - 'log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
                    - 'arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/*'

package:
  include:
    - serverless.yml
```

While deploying serverless is throwing an error.

ERROR: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: every Fn::Join object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a list of strings to be joined or a function that returns a list of strings (such as Fn::GetAZs) to be joined.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8ctv.png)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use `Fn::Join` is:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    secretManagerLambdaRole:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        Policies:
          - PolicyName: myPolicy
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2017'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action:
                    - logs:CreateLogGroup
                    - logs:CreateLogStream
                    - logs:PutLogEvents
                    - ssm:GetParameters
                    - ssm:GetParameter
                    - ssm:DescribeParameters
                  Resource:
                    - 'Fn::Join':
                        - ':' # delimiter
                        - - 'arn:aws:logs'
                          - 'log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*:*'
                          - 'arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/*'
```

The first argument `:` is the delimiter, and the second is a list for strings to concatenate.